# How does the characteristic impedence of a lumped network work?

Tags: s-parameters, characteristic-impedance, power-divider

I'll take a textbook example to explain my problem.

> Find the scattering parameters of the 3 dB attenuator circuit shown in the figure:
> [image: image of the two port lumped network]

The solution reads:

> From (4.41), S11 can be found as the reflection coefficient seen at port 1 when port 2 is terminated in a matched load. Given: \$Z_0 = 50\Omega\$

Here are my questions:

1. Where is this characteristic impedance coming from?
   I understand that characteristic impedance [is not the property of a port.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445680/characteristic-impedance-of-a-port)
2. (Building further on question 1) Is this characteristic impedance coming from an unmentioned transmission line on both ports?
3. When we say "we must match port 2 to find the value of S11 parameter" are we really saying that we must match the transmission line that is present at port 2?
4. If I correctly justified my 3rd question, how does the same concept of 'characteristic impedance' and 'port matching' behave for a waveguide-like device, like a circulator or a directional coupler? Let's look at a T-junction, a 3 port device.

If we assume that all ports are 'matched' and if the network is reciprocal, this is the S matrix we get:

[image: s matrix of T junction with all 3 ports matched]

The S matrix makes perfect sense, but how are we actually matching all ports of the junction?
Is this 'matched ports' idea a property of a good quality T-junction, or is the idea of 'matching' here the same as the lumped network above i.e it is our responsibility to add in correct loads at the respective ports?

Comment: I've rolled-back the question to how it was originally stated when the first answers were provided. Please note (McSuperbX1) that significantly editing a question after an answer is provided is not something that should be undertaken. If you want to ask for a solution to what you added, please raise a brand-new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is this characteristic impedance coming from? I understand that characteristic impedance is not the property of a port.

To find the \$S_{11}\$ or \$S_{12}\$ parameter of a two port network, you place an impedance at port 2. The impedance you place there depends upon the circuit the 2 port network is embedded in. The typical context for an attenuator, of the sort in your question, will consist of the two port network connected at each port to a properly terminated transmission line. Thus the impedance that each port "sees" is the characteristic impedance of the transmission line connected to that port. But remember, that is just a typical context. The attenuator might instead by connected to, say, a low pass filter, or a high pass filter, or ...

> (Building further on question 1) Is this characteristic impedance coming from an unmentioned transmission line on both ports?

The impedance seen by port 2 of your attenuator network might be the characteristic impedance of a transmission line, or it might be the *impedance* (without the qualifier "characteristic") of something else. In either case, what the attenuator is connected to is typically unmentioned. However, when the attenuator is specified, the input and output impedances need to be specified. So typically, one might see an attenuator specified as "6 dB at 50 \$\Omega\$". In this case, *both* ports are assumed to "see" 50 \$\Omega\$ impedances.

> When we say "we must match port 2 to find the value of S11 parameter" are we really saying that we must match the transmission line that is present at port 2?

Again, it is not necessarily a transmission line that is connected to either port. It could be some sort of filter, an antenna, or anything else. But the impedance of that "whatever else" must match the impedance for which the attenuator was designed. If it isn't, the attenuator will not behave as specified.

> If I correctly justified my 3rd question, how does the same concept of 'characteristic impedance' and 'port matching' behave for a waveguide-like device, like a circulator or a directional coupler? Let's look at a T-junction, a 3 port device.

Again, the correct impedance needs to be connected each of the ports for the 3-port network to behave in manner for which it is designed. But those impedances do not need to be the characteristic impedance of a transmission line.

Incidentally, the input impedance of a transmission line is its characteristic impedance only if the transmission line is properly terminated. 10 cm of 50 \$\Omega\$ coaxial cable terminated with an open circuit, does not have a 50 \$\Omega\$ input impedance at 1 MHz.

Comment: Let's say that the second port has some sort of filter (as your rightfully stressed in your answer). How would I go about matching this filter's impedance? In the context of transmission lines, I'd pick a load that matches the characteristic impedance of the transmission line which in turn ensures that there is no voltage wave reflection from port 2. Does this idea of no 'voltage wave' reflection hold true for a filter sitting at port 2?

Comment: @McSuperbX1 a filter is also typically a 2 port network, just like your attenuator. It is designed to work when the input has a specific impedance and the output has a specific impedance. They don't need to be the same. But if a filter is at port 2 of the attenuator, the input impedance for which the filter is designed needs to match the output impedance of the attenuator. You can have a long chain of 2-port networks like this, but somewhere it ends in a 1-port network, i.e. something that has an impedance that does not depend upon its output.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic impedance of a symmetrical pad is Z if, when port 2 is terminated with Z, port 1 presents an impedance of Z.

This means you need to set up an equation for the input impedance of port 1, when port 2 is terminated with a variable impedance, set them equal, and solve.

When working as an RF engineer, I noticed a short cut to this process, which I've not seen documented anywhere else. I'm sure it's just equivalent to solving the equations I mentioned above. The characteristic impedance is given by the geometric mean of the port 1 impedances, when port 2 is open circuit, and short circuit.

Looking at your example, the open circuit impedance is 8.56+141.8 = 150.36. The short circuit is 8.56 + 8.56//141.8 = 8.56 + 8.07 = 16.63. Their geometric mean is sqrt(16.63*150.36) = sqrt(2500) = 50 ohms.

Comment: Hi Neil, unfortunately my confusion is more fundamental. I know how to solve the question and I appreciate your neat trick. I want to know what element/component of the T-Pad dictated this 50 Ohm value of the characteristic impedance? The unmentioned/presumed transmission lines on both ports?

Comment: I've added another example to my question, where the characteristic impedance is already handed to us. I think I realize that the first example was well crafted to make sure S11 and S22 turn out to be 0.

Comment: @McSuperbX1 In your 2nd example, the pad does not have a 50 ohm impedance. The question was telling you that the system has a 50 ohm impedance, and to measure the pad in that. I think 'the' system is a grammatical error. The pad is not symmetrical, so it might be intended to be used between two systems of different impedances.

Comment: @McSuperbX1 To your first comment, no component, or rather all the components, define the characteristic impedance of the pad. When you solve the equation I suggested, or use my sqrt trick, you use the values of all components. It is a characteritics of the pad iteslfe. If measured in a 50 ohmsystem, the S11 etc would be zero. If measured in a 75 ohm system, S11 etc would be finite. 'Measured in a Z ohm system' means taking Z as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Port 1 and port 2 are symmetrical electrically therefore, they will present the same impedance. However, only when the impedance connected on both ports (a driving source at one side and, a load on the other side) is 50 Ω does the attenuation factor become 3 dB for the values shown.

Here's an example from my [basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Taper%20pad%20attenuator.html): -

[image]

I've set the impedances up on both sides to be 50 Ω and the attenuation to be 0.7071 (3.01 dB). As you can see the resistor values are the same as yours.

You can use the formulas to derive the relationship. The taper-pad formulas work with asymmetrical impedances on both sides too.

Comment: They're symmetric in the first example, but not in the second.

Comment: @Hearth I'm afraid it's a case of the OP modifying the question after I answered it.

Comment: Ah, that keeps happening. I had that happen yesterday, too.

Comment: After some thought, I've rolled it back @Hearth